# XmlReader read document with unescaped &s

Tags: c#, xml, xml-entities

I am trying to parse an XMl document that i received into a string from a web service call.

```
String content = ...;//long xml document
using(TextReader reader = new StringReader(content))
using(XmlReader xml_reader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
{
    XML = new XPathDocument(xml_reader);
}
```

however i get an exception :

```
An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 1721.
```

i looked through the document around that character and it was in the middle of a random tag, however about 20-30 chars earlier i noticed that there were unescaped ampersands (& characters), so im thinking that that is the problem.

running:

```
content.Substring(1700, 100);//results in the following text
"alue>1 time per day& with^honey~&water\\\\</Value></Frequency></Direction>          </Directions>     "
                    ^unescaped & char 1721 is the 'w'
```

how can i successful read this document as xml?

Comment: Report this as a bug to the supplier of this XMI.  Their code producing this is wrong and should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify that your xml encoding matches theirs (the top of the document, something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>`).  Substitute the value from the webservice xml document for `webserviceEncoding` below

```
using(XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding(webserviceEncoding)))) {
    XML = new XPathDocument( r );
    // ... 
}
```

**If that doesn't work**

1. Replace it in the string prior to loading it into an xml parser
2. Notify the webservice vendor

Comment: just do content.replace("&", "&amp;")? won't that possibly screw up other parts of the document?

Comment: @luke I wouldn't wholesale replace like that.  Just replace that one instance. Or you could manually (regex) look at all the contents of the value tags and sanitize them.

Comment: You get the check because notifying the xml provider was the right solution.  sometimes its best not to hack the solution together, thanks